# In groovy, is there a way to check if an object has a given method?

Tags: groovy

Assuming that I have an object `someObj` of indeterminate type, I'd like to do something like:

```
def value = someObj.someMethod()
```

Where there's no guarantee that 'someObj' implements the `someMethod()` method, and if it doesn't, just return `null`.

Is there anything like that in Groovy, or do I need to wrap that in an if-statement with an `instanceof` check?

Comment: One way would be to interate `.properties` per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585992/how-to-get-all-property-names-of-a-groovy-class

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use `respondsTo`

```
class Foo {
   String prop
   def bar() { "bar" }
   def bar(String name) { "bar $name" }
}

def f = new Foo()

// Does f have a no-arg bar method
if (f.metaClass.respondsTo(f, "bar")) {
   // do stuff
}
// Does f have a bar method that takes a String param
if (f.metaClass.respondsTo(f, "bar", String)) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just implement methodMissing in your class:

```
class Foo {
   def methodMissing(String name, args) { return null; }
}
```

And then, every time you try to invoke a method that doesn't exist, you will get a null value.

```
def foo = new Foo();
assert foo.someMethod(), null
```

For more information, take a look here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+methodMissing+and+propertyMissing

Comment: That means all his Objects that don't have the someMethod behavior would have to implement the method?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do something like:

```
SomeObj.metaClass.getMetaMethod("someMethod")
```

Or you can fall back to the good old Java reflection API.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by using `getMetaMethod` together with the safe navigation operator `?.`:

```
def str = "foo"
def num = 42

def methodName = "length"
def args = [] as Object[]

assert 3 == str.metaClass.getMetaMethod(methodName, args)?.invoke(str, args);
assert null == num.metaClass.getMetaMethod(methodName, args)?.invoke(num, args);
```

Answer (score 3):

if class :

```
   MyClass.metaClass.methods*.name.any{it=='myMethod'}//true if exist
```

if object :

```
myObj.class.metaClass.methods*.name.any{it=='myMethod'}//true if exist
```

Answer (score -1):

In very concise way you can use this:

```
if(someObj.&methodName){
 //it means someObj has the method
}
```

Comment: I wish it worked !
`someObj.&methodName` always returns a closure, even if no method with given name exists. This must be due to runtime resolution of the method with calling arguments. Cf. https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-operators.html#method-pointer-operator